How to evaluate these Gaussian integrals?
I am reading this paper by Gross and Mezard. In it they calculate the number of solutions to the Thouless-Anderson-Palmer mean field equations for a spin glass model. As an intermediate step (Equations 51 and 52) they have this integral:
\begin{equation}
P(x_1,\dots,x_N)=const\int\prod_{i_1<\dots<i_p}d\hat J_{i_1\dots i_p}\sqrt{\frac{N^{p-1}}{\pi p!}}\exp\left[-\frac{N^{p-1}}{p!}(\hat J_{i_1\dots i_p})^2\right]
\times\int d\lambda_1\dots d\lambda_N\exp\left[i\sum_k\lambda_k\left(x_k-\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i_2<\dots<i_p}\hat J_{ki_2\dots i_p}\right)\right]\\
=\frac{p^{(N-1)/2}}{\pi^{N/2}}\exp\left[-p\left[\sum_kx_k^2-\frac{p-1}{Np}\left(\sum_kx_k\right)^2\right]\right],
\end{equation}
for $N\rightarrow\infty$.
The integrals over $\lambda_k$ are integral representations of delta functions enforcing the constraint $x_k=\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i_2<\dots<i_p}\hat J_{ki_2\dots i_p}$.
I can see that the integral over $J$ is Gaussian and then I think the integral over $\lambda$ will be Gaussian also, but I cannot obtain the same result as the paper. Can you help me understand how this result is reached?
